# Installing laravel app under remote ubuntu/nginx server I got 404 error

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I need to run laravel-app on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
installed under kinsta.com

This OS has nginx installed and php 7.3. I have no big nginx expierence, mostly I worked with apache

From Administration of the site I got that root of my hosting is

```
/www/projectname_339/public/ directory
```

anf in this directory I run

```
git clone ...
```

and have

```
cd /www/projectname_339/public/laravel.projectname.io/

projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io$ la -la
total 635
drwxr-xr-x 15 projectname www-data     29 Jan  6 12:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 projectname www-data      5 Jan  6 15:58 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    213 Jan  5 14:36 .editorconfig
drwxr-xr-x  8 projectname www-data     13 Jan  5 14:36 .git
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    111 Jan  5 14:36 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    186 Jan  5 14:36 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    174 Jan  5 14:36 .styleci.yml
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data      3 Jan  5 14:36 .vscode
drwxr-xr-x 10 projectname www-data     12 Jan  5 14:36 app
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    291 Jan  5 14:36 appspec.yml
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data   1686 Jan  5 14:36 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 projectname www-data      4 Jan  5 14:36 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data   1985 Jan  6 12:51 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data 254883 Jan  6 12:31 composer.lock
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data     17 Jan  5 14:36 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 projectname www-data      6 Jan  5 14:36 database
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data      4 Jan  5 14:36 deploy
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data 826849 Jan  5 14:36 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data   1765 Jan  5 14:36 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data   1156 Jan  5 14:36 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  9 projectname www-data     16 Jan  6 14:12 public
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data   4198 Jan  5 14:36 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  6 projectname www-data      6 Jan  5 14:36 resources
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data      6 Jan  5 14:36 routes
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    563 Jan  5 14:36 server.php
drwxr-xr-x  6 projectname www-data      6 Jan  5 14:36 storage
drwxr-xr-x  4 projectname www-data      6 Jan  5 14:36 tests
drwxr-xr-x 59 projectname www-data     60 Jan  6 12:31 vendor
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    538 Jan  5 14:36 webpack.mix.js
```

and public subdirectory

```
projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io$ cd public
projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io/public$ la -la
total 668
drwxr-xr-x  9 projectname www-data      16 Jan  6 14:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 projectname www-data      29 Jan  6 12:30 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data     593 Jan  5 14:36 .htaccess
drwxr-xr-x  3 projectname www-data       3 Jan  5 14:36 assets
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data       3 Jan  5 14:36 audio
drwxr-xr-x  3 projectname www-data      17 Jan  5 14:36 css
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data       0 Jan  5 14:36 favicon.ico
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data      24 Jan  5 14:36 fonts
drwxr-xr-x  9 projectname www-data      91 Jan  5 14:36 images
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data       4 Jan  5 14:36 img
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    1823 Jan  5 14:36 index.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 projectname www-data      21 Jan  5 14:36 js
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data      71 Jan  5 14:36 mix-manifest.json
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data      24 Jan  5 14:36 robots.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data    1194 Jan  5 14:36 web.config
-rw-r--r--  1 projectname www-data 2347119 Jan  5 14:36 

world_universities_and_domains.json
```

I requested the support of the site to set root app into `/www/projectname_339/public/laravel.projectname.io/public`
directory, what was done.

the problem is that running

```
https://staging.projectname.com
```

OR

```
https://staging.projectname.com/index.php
```

I got error:

```
404 Not Found.  nginx
```

Checking file .htaccess I see :

```
projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io/public$ cat .htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

1. can it be that this file is misconfigured?
   I suppose that nginx has no RewriteEngine mode and tried to open this file to comment this option, but I got error trying to edit this file:

   projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io/public$ sudo nano .htaccess
   [sudo] password for projectname:
   Sorry, user projectname is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/nano .htaccess' as root on xAP-projectname.

What have I to edit in .htaccess file to fix 404 error?
I have no root account, only projectname - which have restricted access.

2. I tried to create info.php file under /public directory and got similar error:

   projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io/public$ sudo nano info.php
   [sudo] password for projectname:
   Sorry, user projectname is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/nano info.php' as root on xAP-projectname.

How can I edit/create files under my projectname account?

Thanks!

Comment: I got error :
projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io/public$ cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
-bash: cd: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/: Permission denied

projectname@xAP-projectname:~/public/laravel.projectname.io/public$ cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
cat: /etc/nginx/sites-available/default: Permission denied

Support of the site answered that they do not share the details of our configuration,

I have communicate with support through my client - very unconvinient

Also any ideas of .htaccess configuration ?

Comment: I entered into the system with command :
ssh projectname@NN.NNN.NNN.NN -p 65NNN
and etnering my projectname password

in console of my OS I run :
$ use sudo 
-bash: use: command not found

Didyou mean it ?

Comment: I have no  root user , only projectname login / password with resricted access

Comment: Yes, I try to communicate with support now.
Have any ideas of .htaccess misconfiguration ?

I wanted to comment line :
RewriteEngine On
as nginx does not support mod_rewrite
Also there could be other misconfigation, not working on nginx ?

Comment: server is responsible to server your website not `.htaccess`

Comment: sorry, i did not catch your last message